# Rails popup with user input mid-way through controller function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form which collects data and a file upload. Within the upload function in my controller, it checks if the parameters passed through the form indicate that the file is a duplicate. After the checks, I want to prompt the user in the case that the file is a duplicate. The issue is that I need the rest of the upload function to wait for that user input before continuing with the upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of HTTP. If you need to handle this asynchronously, then you will need some kind of client-side file upload tool like [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) that can be scripted to check for duplicate data, or you will just have to deal with how web forms work.

It's not possible to cut off an HTTP upload and respond prematurely. You may, however, have a separate HTTP request running on the side to test for duplication based on what data you may have received.

This is an old problem that's never been solved cleanly due to the way browsers work.